# SQLite3 Python: Data type TEXT if null 'N/A'

Tags: python, sqlite, default-value

I would like to know if there is a way of setting a default for the data types.
For example the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will auto increment or how the `NOT NULL`, wont allow `None`. What I would like to have happen, would be that when a `None` type
is entered into a `TEXT` column it will input 'N/A' instead of entering nothing. Is this possible or would I have to write a method that would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the column to have a `DEFAULT`:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
    BAR TEXT DEFAULT "N/A"
)
```

See the [SQLite `TABLE` documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint).

Comment: When I input a `None` or `Null` It still inputs a `None` type, not 'N/A'

Comment: The default is used if you *omit* the column on an insert.